# The Real Numbers and Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\sqrt{1+4x}<2x+1$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ using the Intermediate Value Theorem of Derivatives.

Comment: do we really need IVT for that?

Comment: very tempting to down vote with little research or independent thinking effort.

Comment: (Technically, you only need algebra: $0<x^2\implies0<4x^2\implies\\ 1+4x<1+4x+4x^2\implies\\ 1+4x<(1+2x)^2\implies\\ \sqrt{1+4x}<2x+1$.)

Comment: It may be true that you only need algebra, but that's not what the op asked.

Comment: @DavidSimmons Which is why I only posted that as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+4x}$. Choose any $x \in (0,\infty)$, then by IVT:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(\xi)$$

where $\xi \in (0,x)$.But:

$$f'(\xi)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4\xi+1}}$$

So (because $\sqrt{4\xi+1}>1$):

$$f'(\xi) < 2 $$

Therefore:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{4x+1}-1}{x}<2$$

Finally (because $x>0$):

$$\sqrt{4x+1}<2x+1$$

Comment: Are you using the IVT for derivatives, or the Mean Value Theorem?